# Как установить Windows вместо ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Народ подскажите, пожалуйста, вот хочу избавиться от ubuntu 12.04 и у меня ничего не получается. Не могу открыть диск винды через перезагрузку.

Comment: а F8 жмакаете на стартовом экране?)

Comment: Я не телепат, но возможно, вы хотите сказать что установили Ubuntu, и теперь после перезагрузки не показывает меню для выбора операционной системы. И похоже что после включения питания ПК у вас сразу стартует убунта?  Постарайтесь внятно и последовательно изложить свои действия.

Comment: Прошу прощения за оффтоп, но мне кажется - это карма и уважаемому ТС СУЖДЕНО изучать Ubuntu, искать 10 отличий между Debian и BSD, работать в командной строке, между ужином и завтраком успевать пересобрать ядро.... ну и много других интересных и познавательных занятий.Самое главное - что место поиска правильных ответов выбрано верно:)

Answer (score 4):

"Не можете открыть диск винды" - это значит, что не запускается установочный диск Win? Если да, то в BIOS'е поставьте первым загрузочным девайсом оптический привод: при включении ПК жмите F2 (в основном именно ее, хотя иногда и встречается, что надо жать что-то другое, в любом случае, на экране будет написано, что именно жать), переходите в раздел **Boot**, а там что-то типа **Boot device priority**. Ставите привод на первое место и выходите сохранив изменения.

Если же у Вас не получается загрузить уже установленную Win, то, думаю, поможет это небольшое руководство: [Добавление раздела с Windows в меню GRUB 2](http://rubuntu.ru/blog/457/dobavlenie-razdela-s-windows-v-menju-grub-2.html) или это (в зависимости от того, какая версия GRUB установлена): [Добавления пункта загрузки Windows в меню Grub](http://easylinux.ru/node/14/)

Однако, если Вы устанавливали Ubuntu поверх Win и пересоздавали разделы, грохнув имеющиеся, то вероятнее всего загрузить старую винду уже не получится)

Answer (score 1):

Oparin92, подскажите всё же, что конкретно вам надо! Или снести Убунту, и вместо неё венды поставить - так это любой вендовый установщик делает, надо лишь Убунтовые разделы снести. А вот если две системы нужно - это сложнее. Тогда загрузчик венды ставятся поверх Груба (в другой транскрипции - Граба), и тогда Груб надо восстановить. Это можно сделать либо через установочный диск Линя, либо через Rescatux, который здесь: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/

Answer (score 1):

Также не забываем сначала через Acronis либо через LIveCD удалить раздел линукса который отформатирован в EXT3 либо в EXT4 формате. Если этого не сделать, то при установки винды он просто напросто не увидит этот раздел. Повторюсь либо просто его удалите либо отформатируйте в NTFS формате.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему (а именно по словам "Не могу открыть диск винды через перезагрузку") человеку действительно нужно Win установить и ни что иное.Мануал от создателей "винды": http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-RU/windows7/Installing-and-reinstalling-Windows-7 а это мануал от народных умельцев: http://notebookclub.org/article/windows/5-windows-7-install.html На этих двух страницах содержится исчерпывающее количество информации для того что-бы самостоятельно установить Windows (вне зависимости от того какая сейчас установлена ОС).

Comment: Обратил внимание на то как звучит вопрос "Как установить Windows вместо ubuntu 12.04" и вдруг решил, а случаем в приводе не вставлен диск Ubuntu 12.04 вместо Windows и не это-ли причина того что не получается "открыть диск винды через перезагрузку"?